# Using Javascript to view a hidden div tag in Listview ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<ItemTemplate>
                    <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
                        <td width="10%">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowRoles" runat="server">
                                <asp:Image ID="viewRoles" ImageUrl="/images/pointer-down.gif" runat="server" /></asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                        <td width="50%" align="left">
                            <font face="verdana" size="1">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblParameter"><%#Eval("Name") %></asp:Label>
                            </font>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%" align="center">
                            <font face="verdana" size="1">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblType"><%#Eval("Type.Name")%></asp:Label>
                            </font>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%" align="center">
                            <font face="verdana" size="1">
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRequired"><%#Eval("isGlobal") %></asp:Label>
                            </font>
                        </td>
                        <td width="20%" align="center">
                            <font face="verdana" size="1"><a href='<%#GetRedirectionURL(Eval("ID")) %>'>VIEW</a>
                             </font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div align="left" class="ShowRoles">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server">GROUPS:</asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"><%#Eval("MarjorieRoles") %></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
```

This is the code for my ItemTemplate in a ListView. I want the linkbutton in the first  to show the  fields whenever clicked. I am new to javascript and have absolutely no idea how to go about it. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a specific question, but I can give you a few pointers to help you get started.

1) In HTML, each element on your page is marked with an `id` attribute.  In JavaScript, you can use the function `document.getElementById` to get an element by its id.  You can also use an element's class with `document.getElementsByClass`.

2) And *this* is very important.  Any time you add a server-side control to your page, it will be assigned an id in the resulting HTML that may be completely different from the ID you specify in the mark-up.  In ASP.net, you can get the client-side id by writing `<%= elementId.ClientID %>`.

3) A library like jQuery may be very helpful in simplifying your development.  With jQuery, you would use the `$.click` function to attach an event to the buttons click event.  You can use the `$.show` function to make a hidden element appear.